# Exclude directory path if contains a given string

Tags: python-3.x

I wish to exclude any path from further action, if it includes a string.

Code example:

```
import os

Dirpath = input('What directory path e.g. C:/    ')
FileType = input('What Ext type to search for e.g. txt    ')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(Dirpath):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(FileType):
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

I need to ignore any path with contains Dropbox e.g.

```
c:/Users\ljh36\Dropbox\Shared Folders\walk.tmp
```

Can any guidance be given please ?

Comment: Have you tried doing a `contains` check in the if loop?

Comment: Apologies but I am new to Python programming. How would I use ‘contains’ to test the whole path, not just the actual file name

Answer (score 0):

An example in [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) displays removing a dir named `CVS`
from the dirs list. You can adapt this to your code.

The forward slash in the input string can be changed to a
backslash by using `r` just before the string so you do not
need to escape it with an additional backslash.

```
import os

Dirpath = input(r'What directory path e.g. C:\    ')
FileType = input('What Ext type to search for e.g. txt    ')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(Dirpath):

    # Remove 'Dropbox' from the list of dirs to walk.
    if 'Dropbox' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('Dropbox')

    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(FileType):
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
```